# How can I capture all sentences in a file with the format of (name): (sentence)\n(name):

Tags: python, regex, spacy

I have files of transcripts where the format is

> (name): (sentence)\n (<-- There can be multiples of this pattern)
>
> (name): (sentence)\n
>   (sentence)\n

and so on. I need all of the sentences. So far I have gotten it to work by hard-coding the names in the file, but I need it to be generic.

```
utterances = re.findall(r'(?:CALLER: |\nCALLER:\nCRO: |\nCALLER:\nOPERATOR: |\nCALLER:\nRECORDER: |RECORDER: |CRO: |OPERATOR: )(.*?)(?:CALLER: |RECORDER : |CRO: |OPERATOR: |\nCALLER:\n)', raw_calls, re.DOTALL)
```

Python 3.6 using re. Or if anyone knows how to do this using spacy, that would be a great help, thanks.

I want to just grab the \n after an empty statement, and put it in its own string. And I suppose I will just have to grab the tape information given at the end of this, for example, since I can't think of a way to distinguish if the line is part of someone's speech or not.
Also sometimes, there's more than one word between start of line and colon.

Mock data:

> CRO: How far are you from the World Trade Center, how many blocks, about? Three or
>   four blocks?
>
> 63FDNY 911 Calls Transcript - EMS - Part 1 9-11-01
>
> CALLER:
>
> CRO: You're welcome. Thank you.
>
> OPERATOR: Bye.
>
> CRO: Bye.
>
> RECORDER: The preceding portion of tape concludes at 0913 hours, 36 seconds.
>
> This tape will continue on side B.
>
> OPERATOR NEWELL: blah blah.

Comment: I suspect you will get better responses if you provide sample data so people dont have to spend their own time mocking up data to test the regex.

Comment: Your regular expression seems to be more complex than what you describe it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookahead expression that looks for the same pattern of a name at the beginning of a line and is followed by a colon:

```
s = '''CRO: How far are you from the World Trade Center, how many blocks, about? Three or four blocks?
63FDNY 911 Calls Transcript - EMS - Part 1 9-11-01
CALLER:
CRO: You're welcome. Thank you.
OPERATOR: Bye.
CRO: Bye.
RECORDER: The preceding portion of tape concludes at 0913 hours, 36 seconds.
This tape will continue on side B.
OPERATOR NEWELL: blah blah.
GUY IN DESK: I speak words!'''
import re
from pprint import pprint
pprint(re.findall(r'^([^:\n]+):\s*(.*?)(?=^[^:\n]+?:|\Z)', s, flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL), width=200)
```

This outputs:

```
[('CRO', 'How far are you from the World Trade Center, how many blocks, about? Three or four blocks?\n63FDNY 911 Calls Transcript - EMS - Part 1 9-11-01\n'),
 ('CALLER', ''),
 ('CRO', "You're welcome. Thank you.\n"),
 ('OPERATOR', 'Bye.\n'),
 ('CRO', 'Bye.\n'),
 ('RECORDER', 'The preceding portion of tape concludes at 0913 hours, 36 seconds.\nThis tape will continue on side B.\n'),
 ('OPERATOR NEWELL', 'blah blah.\n'),
 ('GUY IN DESK', 'I speak words!')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You never gave us mock data, so I used the following for testing purposes:

```
name1: Here is a sentence.
name2: Here is another stuff: sentence
which happens to have two lines
name3: Blah.
```

We can try matching using the following pattern:

```
^\S+:\s+((?:(?!^\S+:).)+)
```

This can be explained as:

```
^\S+:\s+           match the name, followed by colon, followed by one or more space
((?:(?!^\S+:).)+)  then match and capture everything up until the next name
```

Note that this handles the edge case of the final sentence, because the negative lookahead used above just would not be true, and hence all remaining content would be captured.

Code sample:

```
import re
line = "name1: Here is a sentence.\nname2: Here is another stuff: sentence\nwhich happens to have two lines\nname3: Blah."
matches = re.findall(r'^\S+:\s+((?:(?!^\S+:).)+)', line, flags=re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
print(matches)

['Here is a sentence.\n', 'Here is another stuff: sentence\nwhich happens to have two lines\n', 'Blah.']
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you, this works quite well. The only case I need now is for multiple words before the colon after the start of a line. Sorry for not giving mock data before.